# Equivalent of Schur basis for partially-symmetric polynomials

Tags: group-theory, commutative-algebra, representation-theory

Suppose we have a tetrahedron with edge lengths $r_{12}$, $r_{13}$, $r_{14}$, $r_{23}$, $r_{24}$, $r_{34}$.

I'm trying to understand the ring of polynomials in $r_{12}$, $r_{13}$, $r_{14}$, $r_{23}$, $r_{24}$, $r_{34}$ that are invariant under permutations of the vertices, i.e., polynomials in 6 variables that have $S_4$ symmetry instead of being fully symmetric. An example of such a polynomial is the Cayley–Menger determinant.

Is there is an analogue of the Schur basis (of fully symmetric polynomials) in this situation?

Comment: The edge lengths will also satisfy some algebraic relations that formal variables wouldn't so are you talking about the polynomial ring in those variables modulo those relations. or do you just want the polynomial ring in formal variables without those relations?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I was going to deal with the relations separately (since in this case they are just triangle inequalities), so I wanted the polynomial ring in formal variables without the relations.

Comment: But in bigger examples (e.g., 5 points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with 10 pairwise distances and $S_5$ symmetry), there are equality relations too I think, so pointers on whether they can be taken into account in choosing a natural basis would be most welcome.